# Html anchor link in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Can anybody tell me about inner HTML link without loading whole page in Android WebView?

My code is here:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:window.location='" + this.anchor + "'");`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This it worked for me

```
cwb_webView.loadUrl("javascript:removeHtmlElementBorder( '"+prevHashTag+"' )");
    cwb_webView.loadUrl("javascript:setHtmlElementBorder( '"+path+"' )");
    cwb_webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('"+path+"').scrollIntoView(true);")
```

;

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution i found.
view.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.hash='" + test + "'");`